# Spring Autowiring calling wrong constructor

Tags: java, spring, constructor, autowired

I'm learning `Springs` with annotations and auto wiring. I tried three types of auto wiring

1. Constructor
2. Setter injection
3. Method

This is my configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- add entry for component scanning -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.aht.spring.entity"></context:component-scan>

</beans>
```

These are my entities

**Coach.java**

```
package com.aht.spring.entity.coach;

public interface Coach {

    String getDailyWorkOut();

    String getDailyFortune();
}
```

**FortuneService**

```
package com.aht.spring.entity.fortune;

public interface FortuneService {

    String getFortune();
}
```

**HappyFortuneService**

```
package com.aht.spring.entity.fortune;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class HappyFortuneService implements FortuneService {

    public String getFortune() {
        return "Feel energetic for first half of trainning";
    }
}
```

**FootBallCoach**

```
package com.aht.spring.entity.coach;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.aht.spring.entity.fortune.FortuneService;

@Component
public class FootBallCoach implements Coach {

    private FortuneService fortuneService;

    @Autowired
    public FootBallCoach(FortuneService fortuneService) {
        this.fortuneService = fortuneService;
    }

    public String getDailyWorkOut() {
        return "Practice one-on-one for 2 hours";
    }

    public String getDailyFortune() {
        return fortuneService.getFortune();
    }
}
```

**CricketCoach**

```
package com.aht.spring.entity.coach;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.aht.spring.entity.fortune.FortuneService;

@Component
public class CricketCoach implements Coach {

    private FortuneService fortuneService;

    public CricketCoach() {
        System.out.println("Default constructor");
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setFortuneService(FortuneService fortuneService) {
        this.fortuneService = fortuneService;
    }

    public String getDailyWorkOut() {
        return "Practice out field tips";
    }

    public String getDailyFortune() {
        return fortuneService.getFortune();
    }
}
```

**BaseBallCoach**

```
package com.aht.spring.entity.coach;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.aht.spring.entity.fortune.FortuneService;

@Component
public class BaseBallCoach implements Coach {

    private FortuneService fortuneService;

    public String getDailyWorkOut() {
        return "Practice curve whole day";
    }

    public String getDailyFortune() {
        return fortuneService.getFortune();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void customAutoWire(FortuneService fortuneService) {
        this.fortuneService = fortuneService;
    }
}
```

I've three classes for executing three ways of auto wiring, Constructor and Setter worked fine, but when `method` wise auto wiring was done a wrong constructor was called. One thing I missed in my in my `BaseBallCoach` class was a default constructor, but anyhow compiler will automatically generate one for me right?

This is my **CoachMethodInjectionApp.java** where I executed method auto wiring

```
package com.aht.spring.app;

import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.aht.spring.entity.coach.Coach;

public class CoachMethodInjectionApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //  read config-file
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");

        //  get beans
        Coach coach = context.getBean("baseBallCoach", Coach.class);

        //  get dependencies
        System.out.println(coach.getDailyFortune());

        //  get daily workout
        System.out.println(coach.getDailyWorkOut());

        //  close context
        context.close();
    }
}
```

This was the output

```
Default constructor
Feel energetic for first half of trainning
Practice curve whole day
```

First line of output is what I don't understand `Default constructor`, why the constructor of `CricketCoach` executing??

Comment: The `CricketCoach` class is annotated with `@Component` and probably the packages are scanned and an instance needs to be created, so the constructor is called

Comment: Yes; I agree with @ValentinCarnu In order to inject the instance it must be created and in this case it is create by using the default constructor

Comment: @Valentin Carnubut you are right, when I kept separate print line statements in all three constructors all got printed, but I only asked for `BaseBallCoach` instance

Comment: All the beans defined in the xml file or annotated with `@Component` or any extension of `@Component` from scanned packages are created at start-up no matter whether they will be used or not

Comment: @ValentinCarnu make that an answer ! Arun, try adding a constructor to every component; they should all be called during the Spring component scan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As `CricketCoach` class is annotated with `@Component` and the package is scanned when the Spring container starts it will create an instance of type `CricketCoach` by calling the no-arg constructor

All the beans defined in the xml file or annotated with `@Component` or any extension of `@Component` from scanned packages will be created at start time of the spring container no matter if they will be used or not

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a new instance of Coach class here:
`Coach coach = context.getBean("baseBallCoach", Coach.class);`
Everytime new instance is created it is executing a constructor. In which you have call to `System.out.println("Default constructor");`. You may try removing @Component from Cricket Coach imlpementation.

Comment: Have you tried removing @Component from CircketCoach? I believe for autowiring there can be only 1 Component that qulifies for it.